# Express Checkout Sandbox Issue: "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment....."

Tags: paypal-sandbox

My development environment for Paypal Sandbox Express Checkout via NVP Signature from last Friday afternoon (09 Oct 2015) will always return below error

> "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a
>   different debit or credit card number."

I've tried several credit cards and it always return this same message.

Previously, before last Friday afternoon , it was working fine. Tested a same credit card that did not work in sandbox in live endpoint and the credit card works.

Can someone help? Or is someone experiencing this same issue?

Thanks!